# How to fix a spring in brake lever?

Tags: brakes

I was wondering if there was any quick fix for a broken spring in a Pro-Max 239A brake lever. It seems a waste to buy a new one for a broken spring.

Comment: If you can remove the broken spring you can try to find a similar replacement. Try https://www.mcmaster.com/springs.

Comment: Does it really need to be replaced? Usually the return springs in the brake calipers are strong enough to pull the lever back too.

Comment: @WaltoSalonen I pulled out the old spring & now the lever returns better than it did. Seems to be OK, as you say. I’ll try with this and replace if it’s not good enough. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of component-level repair is rare in cycling.  Generally speaking a shop would fit a new replacement brake lever and clamp.  Moving sub-components around would be the realm of someone valuing a period-correct part over functionality.

I'd replace both brake levers with either new or a good quality used replacement.

Why both?  So they feel the same when in use, with similar action and pivot distances.

**Brakes are a critical safety component**, and I'd think very carefully before twiddling internal parts around and using a generic item as a replacement.